# Why are bash script variables not saving?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr
EC2_HOME=~/ec2-api
echo $EC2_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
```

I run the script like so

```
$ ./ec2
/Users/user/ec2-api
```

The script runs and produces the correct output.

However, when I now try to access the EC2_HOME variable, I get nothing out:

```
$ echo $EC2_HOME
```

I get a blank string back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do either of the following instead:

```
source ec2
```

or

```
. ec2
```

(note the `.` notation is just a shortcut for `source`)

**Explanation:**

- This is because `./ec2` actually spawns a subshell from your current shell to execute the script, and subshells cannot affect the environment of the parent shell from which it spawned.
- Thus, `EC2_HOME` does get set to `/Users/user/ec2-api` correctly in the subshell (and similarly the `PATH` environment variable is updated and exported correctly in the subshell as well), but those changes won't propagate back to your parent shell.
- Using `source` runs the script directly in the current shell without spawning a subshell, so the changes made will persist.
- (A note on `export`: export is used to tell new shells spawned from the current shell to use the variables exported from the current shell. So for any variables you would only use in the current shell, they need not be exported.)

Answer (score 0):

A shell script can never modify the environment of their parent.
To fix your problem, you can use the dot (.) command:

```
$ . ./ec2
```

and that should work. In cshell, it would be

```
% source ./ec2
```

To learn more about shells and scripts, my best resource is by far [Unix power tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003307).